# "Cannot resolve symbol" error in Visual Studio 2008?

Tags: asp.net, code-generation, resharper, dataset

I have started working on some code left behind by previous developers, and I'm having a strange issue with it. The code is C# in ASP.NET 2.0, and I'm using ReSharper 4.1 in Visual Studio 2008.

This code compiles just fine and works in my Web app, but ReSharper is barfing on it with the message, "Cannot resolve symbol `'<name of class here>'`". It's not the end of the world, but I'd rather not have tons of red errors in my code files.

A sample line:

`InvoiceItem invoiceItems = GetInvoiceItems(serviceLineItemID);`

`InvoiceItem` is an .xsd dataset with automatically generated .cs code-behind. In the past, I've used xsd.exe to create the .cs files for datasets, and included the .cs in my project, but that won't work in this situation. I've been a .NET developer for a long time, but this is the first time I've run into this issue.

Any ideas?

Comment: For me works just delete resharper's folder in the project's folder!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It may be a bug in resharper, disable resharper and see if it still happens. If so, report the bug to resharper. They're usually pretty responsive.

Comment: definitely something to do with the resharper, after I suspend it, the error gone!

Answer (score 1):

I know it's a bit late but I just confirmed that build 1212 seems to be working with automatically generated code.

Answer (score 0):

May be a bug in ReSharper. You could try ReSharper 4.5 [nightly builds](http://www.jetbrains.net/confluence/display/ReSharper/ReSharper+4.5+Nightly+Builds) (pre-release) to see if it is already fixed for this version. If not, please file a bug in our issue tracker ([instructions](http://www.jetbrains.net/confluence/display/ReSharper/ReSharper+Issue+Tracker)). Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you used ReSharper to clean the code it'll sometimes update the namespace on the code page but not the design side.  It'll all so shorten control registration for referenced dlls.  Sometimes it works, sometimes it doesn't.

edit: wow, this is old ... need to start looking at the dates ...

Comment: "old" it may be, but I'm having the same issue in VS2010 and ReSharper 6.0. Disabling Resharper surprisingly made the issue go away (after more than an hour of banging things near in a random panic).